# I have 8 rows but when (i = 7) it says (i + 1) is out of range?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, rowcount, outofrangeexception

I have a `DataGridView` with `8 Rows`. In the following `Sub` i have an `If` statement to only do something when `i` is less than the `RowCount`, this is purposely so when i use `(i + 1)` on the last row it will still be in range, yet it is not? I can't figure out why. Would appreciate any help.

This is the `sub`

```
    Public Sub Durations(dgv As DataGridView)
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.RowCount

        Dim intTotalMinutesOfRows As Integer
        Dim IntHoursForRows As Integer
        Dim intMinutesForRows As Integer

        If i < dgv.RowCount Then

            If dgv.Rows(i).Cells("EmployeeID").Value = dgv.Rows(i + 1).Cells("EmployeeID").Value _
            And dgv.Rows(i).Cells("Date").Value = dgv.Rows(i + 1).Cells("Date").Value Then

                intTotalMinutesOfRows = intTotalMinutesOfRows + dgv.Rows(i).Cells("TotalDurationOfRow").Value

            Else

                intTotalMinutesOfRows = intTotalMinutesOfRows + dgv.Rows(i).Cells("TotalDurationOfRow").Value
                IntHoursForRows = Math.Floor(intTotalMinutesOfRows / 60)
                intMinutesForRows = intTotalMinutesOfRows Mod 60
                dgv.Rows(i).Cells("TotalDurationForDay").Value = "" & IntHoursForRows & " Hrs     " & intMinutesForRows & " Mins"
                intTotalMinutesOfRows = 0
            End If

        End If

    Next
```

Comment: 0 counts as a row...so you need to loop from 0 to RowCount-1

Comment: That's how i had it before but it was giving the same error although i will do it again now.

Comment: you may have to tweak your if statement as well as references like this "dgv.Rows(i + 1)".  that i+1 will give you issues on your last iteration...

Comment: Thank you both they do remove the error so it loads fine, just the last row Is missing it's total duration, i thought that was because the last row was being missed but now i see it's just not being handled.

Comment: DataGrid**View**. You should be doing all your operations on an underlying non-ui datasource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate to `RowCount - 1` only:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1
                                     ^^^
```

Note that despite you've got `If i < dgv.RowCount Then`, later in this conditional operator you're trying to access `Rows(i + 1)`, which causes the exception for `i = dgv.RowCount - 1`. So you have to change your condition to `If i < dgv.RowCount - 1 Then` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Indexes are zero-based (they start at 0), so index 7 is the 8th row.

```
Row   :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
Index :  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Infact even your loop's end is wrong, because `i` will go to whatever `RowCount` is. Thus if `RowCount` is 8 then `i` will be 8 as well in the end (which doesn't work, as seen in the indexes above).

In order to loop to the last index you must loop to `RowCount - 1`:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1
```

Comment: The `RowCount -1` has solved the error, i see now that the last `Row` will fail the `If` statement and that's why there is no Total Duration displayed. I just need to do that now.

What i didn't understand is if there is `8 Rows` then why on the 7th `Row` is the next one out of range?

EDIT : Sat here thinking about it and i think the penny has dropped finally! Because `i` is the `index` not the `Row` So when `i` is 7 then that IS the last `Row`     Got it

Comment: @DIMPeteAsUsername : Hehe, all the stuff to remember about arrays and indexes can be tricky ;). Good that you now understand the problem! Good luck!

Comment: Good illustration of the row and index. Never thought to explain it like that before.